# Language of labels in MapView

Tags: android, google-api

I have a `MapView` inside a `MapActivity`.
I use my GPS class to get a Lat/Lon and create a `GeoPoint`.
Then I pan and zoom to the current location.

The labels are in English. Is there any way to control the language of the labels displayed on the map?

Comment: Yes there is

Visit this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422246/other-languages-locales-in-mapview-android>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps have local names for each label and also English translation/Latin script. I'm afraid that there is no such options. But I have idea. You can use Google Places API and parse the name (local name as well) from the output of the API (look around for examples) and show it above your own pin.