# Other languages/locales in MapView (android)

Tags: android, android-mapview

Can anyone tell me how to set the mapview object in android so it will display streetnames in other languages, such as hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

After doing much research and playing around I found that the solution is extremely simple:
in your MapActivity.onCreate method you can ovverride the default locale with one line of code, the following is for hebrew:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("iw","IL"));
```

Thats it. I have verified this on my Evo 4g and nexus one. 
Please note that this changed the locale for your entire activity so if you have any localized resources they will be affected as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Maps automatically displays place names in the local language of each country. While **it's not possible to change the language of the place names**, you can search for some major cities and locations in a number of different languages. [--via Google](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63471)

I'm sure it works the same way with android apps.